# Output is not desirable using while loop in python 3.8

Tags: python

Hey I have been writing a code for dictionary, but I have been facing some problem. I am new to python so i couldn't figure it out.
I have used the while loop to iterate it until not get desired option but if you input the required option it does not go into if, else conditions and return 'none' as output.But if I enter wrong output first then the right output, it works fine.

here is my code:

> ```
> def dict(word):
>     word = word.lower()
>     if word in data:
>         return data[word]
>     elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
>         yn = input("Did you mean %s instead?Enter Y if yes or N if no >> " % get_close_matches(word,data.keys(), cutoff=0.8)[0])
>         yn = yn.lower()
>         while not yn in ("yes", "y", "no", "n"):
>             yn = input("Please try Again: ")
>
>             if yn == "y" or yn == "yes":
>                 return data[get_close_matches(word,data.keys(), cutoff=0.8)[0]]
>             elif yn =="n" or yn == "no":
>                 return "Word not Found. Please Check if you have typed the right word.\n "
>             else:
>                 return "We did not understand your query. Please try Again!  "
>     else:
>         return "Word not Found. Please Check if you have typed the right word.\n "
> ```

Here is output I get when use the right input:

> ```
> Enter Word: rainn
> Did you mean rain instead?Enter Y if yes or N if no >> Y
> None
> ```

Here is output I get when use the wrong input first:

> ```
> Enter Word: rainn
> Did you mean rain instead?Enter Y if yes or N if no >> p
> Please try Again: y
> Precipitation in the form of liquid water drops with diameters greater than 0.5 millimetres.
> To fall from the clouds in drops of water.
> ```

Comment: `if elif else` should be outside `while`.

Comment: Have you done any debugging?

Comment: I would not recommend using "dict" as the name for your function, since Python already uses that as the name of its built-in dictionary type.

Answer (score 1):

Indentation problem. Correction below :

```
def dict(word):
    word = word.lower()
    if word in data:
        return data[word]
    elif len(get_close_matches(word, data.keys())) > 0:
        yn = input("Did you mean %s instead?Enter Y if yes or N if no >> " % get_close_matches(word,data.keys(), cutoff=0.8)[0])
        yn = yn.lower()
        while not yn in ("yes", "y", "no", "n"):
            yn = input("Please try Again: ")

        if yn == "y" or yn == "yes":
            return data[get_close_matches(word,data.keys(), cutoff=0.8)[0]]
        elif yn =="n" or yn == "no":
            return "Word not Found. Please Check if you have typed the right word.\n "
        else:
            return "We did not understand your query. Please try Again!  "
    else:
        return "Word not Found. Please Check if you have typed the right word.\n "
```